# Linear Transformation and spanning set

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question below:

> Let $V$ and $W$ be real vector spaces and $T:V\to W$ be a linear transformation 
>   such that $\ker(T) = {0} \subset V$. Let vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ belong to $V$, and $\{T(v_1), T(v_2)\}$ is a generating set for W.
>   Is the set of vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ belonging to $V$ a generating set for $V$?

I found this question from an old book. The more current books I think use the word spanning set instead of generating set.
I am not sure how to start this proof off.
My initial guess is to assume

> $w1$ = $T(v1)$, $w2$ = $T(v2)$, so $\{w1,w2\}$ is the spanning set in $W$. Such that some vector $wi$ in $W$ can be represented as $wi$ = a$w1$ + b$w2$. Then by linearity I guess that we can write $wi$ = $T( a$v1$+ b $v2$)$ .

From this point I am stuck to how to show that these 2 vectors are a spanning set for V, and if I can do that, I guess I can then add v3 and v4 to the first two and claim this is a spanning set for V, because a spanning set can have redundant vectors, this is not asking for a basis set, but a spanning set.
Hope someone can help here.

Palu

Answer (score 1):

First of all, mentioning the vectors $v_3$ and $v_4$ is pure smoke and mirrors, since we know nothing about them (they could even be zero). What is important is the fact that $\ker(T)=0$. This shows that $T$ is injective, so that the image $T(V)$ is isomorphic to $V$. Moreover the fact that $T(v_1)$ and $T(v_2)$ generate $W$ implies that $T$ is also surjective, so $T$ is an isomorphism, and $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic and thus $T(V)=W$. To show that $v_1$ and $v_2$ span $V$ take any vector $v \in V$, take it's image $T(v)$ in $W$ and decompose $T(v)=aw_1+bw_2$ and then take inverse images $v:=av1+bv_2$. This can only happen when $T$ is an isomorphism. An example where $T$ is not injective is given is T is the map $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by the matrix $
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&-2\\
2&-4\\                
\end{array}\right)
$. The vectors $v_1=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\                
\end{array}\right)$ and The vectors $v_2=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1\\                
\end{array}\right)$ span the vectorspace $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ but their images by $T$ do not.

Comment: I just want to add a note.  We don't necessarily know that $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ are linearly independent from each other, unless I'm mistaken.  I don't think $\{ T(v_{1}), T(v_{2}) \}$ being a "generating set" necessarily means it is a basis.  It doesn't affect your answer, but it is just an extra note.

Comment: Thanks Nimda. So you have shown that only v1 and v2 span V and hence all of v1,v2,v3,v4 do not span V. Am I concluding correctly.

Comment: Hi user46944, yes  you are correct, w1,w2 is a spanning set, not a basis and it is also correct that we don't know if these vectors, either vi or wi are independent.

Comment: Hi Nimba, yes since one takes inverse images, and get that a general vector v=av1+bv2, then we have a vector spanned by v1,v2 and then I guess one can by extension add in v3, v4, and hence have all of them become the spanning set (we can do this since we are looking for a spanning set and not a basis, we can allow these redundant vectors). So hence all 4 vectors we can say span the space V. Please let me your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**: Since $W$ have a spanning set with two elements this means
$\dim(W)\leq2$

Also note that $T$ is $1-1$ since it have a trivial kernel, this
means $\dim(V)\leq\dim(W)\leq2$

Now - what in general can we say about $\dim(T(V))$ ?

Added in the comments:

Look at the set of inequalities we got: $$\dim(W)=\dim(T(V))\leq\dim(V)\leq\dim(W)$$
and thus $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$ and since $T$ is $1-1$ it is also onto.
Now, since $\{T(v_{1}),T(v_{2})\}$ spans $W$ it have a subset that
is a basis of $W$ (if $\dim(W)=2$ then it is simply $\{T(v_{1}),T(v_{2})\}$
and if $\dim(W)=1$ it is $\{T(v_{1})\}$ or $\{T(v_{2}\}$)

and $T^{-1}$
is also an isomorphism since $T$ is and it will map a basis to a
basis so $\{v_{1},v_{2}\}$ or $\{v_{1}\}$ or $\{v_{2}\}$ is a basis
for $V$

Comment: I am not sure about dim(T(V)), isnt that just dim(W). But from your second line, does that mean that in V that its dim is MAX 2?

Comment: @Palu $\dim(T(V))\leq\dim(V)$ and yes

Comment: Hi and thanks. So I guess that dim(T(V)) is not in general all of dim(W), T(V)could be a subset of W. SO if dimension is say 2, then we can say that the number of vectors forming a basis in V is 2 vectors, but I can add the other 2 vectors, v3 & v4, and conclude that vectors, v1,v2,v3,v4 is a spanning set for V.

Comment: @Palu -

In general no, but look at the set of inequalities we got: $\dim(W)=\dim(T(V))\leq\dim(V)\leq\dim(W)$
and thus $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$ and since $T$ is $1-1$ it is also onto.
Now, since $\{T(v_{1}),T(v_{2})\}$ spans $W$ it have a subset that
is a basis of $W$ (if $\dim(W)=2$ then it is simply $\{T(v_{1}),T(v_{2})\}$
and if $\dim(W)=1$it is $\{T(v_{1})\}$ or $\{T(v_{2}\}$) and $T^{-1}$
is also an isomorphism since $T$ is and it will map a basis to a
basis so $\{v_{1},v_{2}\}$ or $\{v_{1}\}$ or $\{v_{2}\}$ is a basis
for $V$

Comment: SO based on what you say, we have multiple possibilities, but these are all basis. The questions is asking for spanning set. SO if you say I cannot state v1,...,v4 is a spanning set, and I only look at the possibilities you state as basis, THEN I guess one is forced to conclude that v1,v2,v3,v4, all these together, is not a spanning set for V.

Comment: @Palu You don't have to look at all possibilities, you can say that since
$T^{-1}$ maps a basis of $W$ to a basis of $V$ then if $S\subseteq W$
contains a basis of $W$ then $T^{-1}(S)$ contains a basis for $V$.
This is because if $U\subseteq S$ is a basis for $W$ then $V=T^{-1}(U)\subseteq T^{-1}(S)\subseteq V$
so $T^{-1}(S)=V$ as well

Comment: Hi Belgi, based on what you say then, I conclude that I can say that the maximal set of vectors to span in V is v1,v2. Hence all vectors v1,v2,v3,v4 do not span V, only {v1,v2}. Also note, that we are not dealing with basis only span, we do not have enough info to say it is a basis. BUT, if T is an isomorphism, does that mean that these vectors w that span the vector space, do they automatically become a basis. P

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with your understanding of the term "span of a set - you wrote that "hence all vectors v1,v2,v3,v4 do not span V, only {v1,v2}" please go over the definition of span of a subset again - then verify that what you wrote is not true

Comment: Hi, I know that if one finds a set of basis vectors(all independent), then if one adds some more vectors(hence dependent), these together can form a spanning set.

Comment: BUT, so far, we are only dealing with spanning sets that are not basis vectors. You bring up basis vectors, but I don't see evidence of basis vectors in the question. P